# form variables by one search button?

Tags: php, html

Web site: www.matka-opas.com/ahaa4.php
If i push SEARCH-1 and then SEARCH-2 it works ok,
but how it could do by one search button ?

```
<?php
$depairport = $_POST['depairport'];
$ddestination = $_POST['ddestination'];
$ddday = $_POST['ddday'];
$depmonth = $_POST['depmonth'];
$depyear = $_POST['depyear'];
$retday = $_POST['retday'];
$retmonth = $_POST['retmonth'];
$retyear = $_POST['retyear'];
$aikuisia = $_POST['aikuisia'];
$osoite = $depairport . $ddestination . $ddday . $depmonth . $retday . $retmonth;

?>

<form method="post">



<input type="submit" value="SEARCH 1">

<a href="http://www.travelstart.fi/combo/ <?php echo $osoite; ?>" ><input type="submit" value="SEARCH 2"></a>
```

thanks ! ;]

Comment: As far as I understand you want to post your form, calculate url in your php and redirect to that url on the travel website?

Answer (score 2):

> If i push SEARCH-1 and then SEARCH-2
>   it works ok, but how it could do by
>   one search button ?

Just specify **one** search button and it will submit the form it is under. *And you shouldn't be specifying more than one submit button for a particular form.*

Here is what you should have:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  .............
  .............
  .............
  <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```

Comment: Why can't you use multiple submit buttons per form? If you give them proper names and values Is see no problem.

Comment: @Jan: Why should you have more than one submit button for one form?

Comment: Why not? you are being restrictive so it's up to you to give a proper reason. But here is mine: Suppose I want some submit buttons that represent a choice. So I can eliminate one set of radiobuttons. Is that such strange functionality?

Comment: As far as I know it is valid Html and I think it is not any less semantic than radiobuttons. Please explain why if you don't agree with that.

Comment: @Jan: You can not compare radio buttons with submit buttons. More than one radio button can be put inside a form as per their usage but submit button can be used once per form. I won't be replying any more. You can research on this :)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types  I'm just trying to help you.  quote: `Use multiple submit buttons (each with its own image) in place of a single graphical submit button. Authors may use style sheets to control the positioning of these buttons.` Seems a pretty semantic approach to me.

Comment: @Jan: Now +1 for you answer :)

Comment: Actually, multiple submit buttons used everywhere. Example: in an e-commerce app, one can be "Add to Cart", and the other can be "Buy Now". You can see such usage in many (large) websites.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to submit your form to http://www.travelstart.fi/combo/ you should put the url in the action attribute of the form. Your form will be posted to that url when it is submitted with `<input type="submit" value="SEARCH">`

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.travelstart.fi/combo/">
```

You also might want to learn more about semantic web and the separation of content and markup. I can understand you want to use tables in this kind of layout but 3 `<br>` to create a top margin? I saw you included a stylesheet in your page so...

EDIT: Now that your question is updated I think I understand it better. If you don't need any server-side functionality to calculate the url it might be better to put this functionality in javascript. This means it will be executed inside the browser. This saves you a round-trip to the server and so makes your page navigate a lot faster. This is a quick setup to get you started:

```
<form id="myForm">
  ...
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  myForm.onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.travelstart.fi/combo/' + myForm.depairport +  myForm.ddestination + myForm.ddday + myForm.depmonth + myForm.depyear + myForm.retday + myForm.retmonth + myForm.retyear + myForm.aikuisia;
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

As a disclaimer: this is not the best way to program it, it is just a short example to guide you in the right direction. Getting the right javascript code for what you want to achieve is a different question on SO.

It will probably not work right away since I don't think that will result in a valid url but I hope you get the picture. To make it cross-browser compatible you might want to use a javascript library like JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to submit data

```
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH 1">
```

and then go to different url

```
<a href="http://www.tra velstart.fi/combo/ " ><input type="submit" value="SEARCH 2"></a>
```

to combine this you can use php that would detect a submit and redirect user to a different page...

as example:

```
$depairport = $_POST['depairport'];
$ddestination = $_POST['ddestination'];
$ddday = $_POST['ddday'];
$depmonth = $_POST['depmonth'];
$depyear = $_POST['depyear'];
$retday = $_POST['retday'];
$retmonth = $_POST['retmonth'];
$retyear = $_POST['retyear'];
$aikuisia = $_POST['aikuisia'];
$osoite = $depairport . $ddestination . $ddday . $depmonth . $retday . $retmonth;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
   header( 'http://www.travelstart.fi/combo/'.$osoite ) ; }
```

you might want to change html just to:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="SEARCH 1">
```

thats all - make sure You are using POST method submiting the data